# batch in current dir referencing current dir files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Please be gentle. First post from an extreme novice. I don't even know if this is the right place for this

I managed to create some batch files, scripts and lisps that work but are hard coded to a specific folder on my C:drive. I would like to be able to copy the .bat/.scr/.lsp to network project folders and have them run on whatever files are added to that specific folder. We batch process files before sharing them.  Below is the current .bat that only works when I copy the files to be precessed, into my C:\BATCHING folder. I can't figure out where or how to add the `%cd%` or `%~dp0` modifiers.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO 1. AutoCAD C3D 2015
ECHO 2. AutoCAD Map 2017
ECHO.

CHOICE /C 12 /M "Enter your Choice:"

:: Note - list ERRORLEVELS in decreasing order
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO c3d2017
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO c3d2015

:c3d2015
FOR %%V IN (C:\BATCHING\*.dwg) DO start "T" /w "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\acad.exe" "%%V" /b "C:\BATCHING\insert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
GOTO End

:c3d2017
FOR %%V IN (C:\BATCHING\*.dwg) DO start "T" /w "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2017\acad.exe" "%%V" /b "C:\BATCHING\insert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
GOTO End

:End
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want (just showing the modifications):

```
:c3d2015
FOR %%V IN (%~dp0*.dwg) DO start "T" /w "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\acad.exe" "%%~fV" /b "%%~dpVinsert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
GOTO End

:c3d2017
FOR %%V IN (%~dp0*.dwg) DO start "T" /w "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2017\acad.exe" "%%~fV" /b "%%~dpVinsert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
GOTO End
```

Comment: Thanks @paul. That got me pointed in the right direction. I was able to modify it slightly to make it work.  this was the final format: `:c3d2017
FOR %%V IN (*.dwg) DO start "T" /w "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2017\acad.exe" "%%~fV" /b "%%~dpVinsert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
GOTO End`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @paul. That got me pointed in the right direction. I was able to modify it slightly to make it work. This was the final format:

```
:c3d2017
FOR %%V IN (*.dwg) DO start "T" /w "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2017\acad.exe" "%%~fV" /b "%%~dpVinsert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
GOTO End
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the amount of code and still use your reported working execution string.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "VAR=5"
CLS
ECHO 1. AutoCAD C3D 2015
ECHO 2. AutoCAD Map 2017
ECHO.

CHOICE /C 12 /M "Enter your Choice:"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET "VAR=7"

FOR %%A IN (*.dwg) DO START "" /W "%ProgramFiles%\Autodesk\AutoCAD 201%VAR%\acad.exe" "%%~fA" /b "%%~dpAinsert E-FILE DISCLAIMER layout.scr"
```